# External hard drive "File system check exit code is 8." on Mac

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

Unable to mount external hard drive on Mac, getting this when running first aid:

[image]

I had to shut down my computer because it froze, potentially because I used all the disk space and kept writing to it, but I'm not sure.

I don't have any backups or anything.

Basically wondering what my options are, wondering what I am todo. If there is a way to recover the data from it and/or fix the drive.

Update. Yay, just got this message. But still don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: I'd do what it says. If it's not already backed up, back it up now & reformat. it's simpler than trying to fumble through Terminal & cheaper than DiskWarrior or Paragon Hard Disk Manager [which might not work anyway].

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to repair this drive with a 3rd party software rather recover the data using a data recovery software. The data is very much contained however the directory seems to be failing. Try Stellar or Data Rescue, both can help you recover your data.
Erase the unmounted drive with a new filesystem via Disk Utility but only when you have recovered your files.